# Lifetime and Initialization for Java REST service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs

I'm looking to implement a very simple REST web service in Java. This is not my primary line of work, so everything is new to me.

I've been researching Java and JAX-RS implementations. They do not appear to be that difficult, but I haven't been able to understand the lifetime of the service and how it is created by the web server.

I'm afraid that my service may have to do some costly initialization, such as load a bunch of setup data from a file or resource in order to be able to process the requests. I do not know if I want it to have to do that each time it has to process a request.

So, my question is, what is the lifetime of my service? Can I load a bunch of parameters for my web service from a file before responding to requests? The parameters I need to load do not change and should be the same for all requests (therefore, it is stateless), but I'll need to be able to load that data from somewhere and I'm worried that it will forced to do it for each request. So, can my web service "live" or be cached such that it only needs to do that initialization once, or once per thread, but not once per request?

edit: I haven't decided yet which JAX-RS implementation to use or which server. I'm just interested in the fact that, it can be done, and if it matters which implementation I choose.

Answer (score 3):

Just give an example using Jersey which is an implementatin of JAX-RS. The default life-cycle of root resource class is each request creates its own instance as specified [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2293). So if you have some initial setup in the service and if they are the same for all requests, then you can put them in the static field of resource class and use static block to initialize them since static variables are created on per class basis. Something like this:

```
private static MyParam params;

static {
    params = new MyParam("/path/to/file/setup.conf");
}
```